# Reject unmapped method request in aws API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a lambda running with bunch of APIs. For example consider the below details, Sample API example,

**PATH**: /aws/test/save

**METHOD**: POST

My API gateway has the above path with POST method and if I make a API call with POST method the lambda will initialize and the do the defined action.

**Problem Statement**: If I make same API call with GET method I am getting 405 as expected but it's spinning up the lambda function, which I don't want.

**What I am expecting**: Is it possible to reject the GET request which is not at all mapped in the API gate for the above path.

**NOTE**: Basically only the mapped path with assigned method should start the lambda all other unmapped path or method should be rejected and should not start the lambda.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Lambda server". If you defined paths in API Gateway and mapped them to your Lambda functions (without setting up a greedy proxy path), API Gateway will automatically reject the request. If you set up the greedy proxy than of course that API Gateway will invoke your Lambda function which will route requests in your API further

Comment: @Caldazar, thanks for the answer.  My API gateway had greedy proxy. I had removed it earlier but forget to redeploy the API. It's working as expected.